# URL expiry date calculated incorrectly on server

Tags: java

I am trying to solve an issue where an activation URL in an email to a user is getting expired within 3 days. The expiry date is set to 90 days. When a sample java code is executed, it shows the expiry date correctly, post 90 days. However, on the server where the application is deployed, the URL is expiring within 3 days of user receiving the email with the URL to activate.

From the server log:

```
Plain Text Output=webChannel=GMD_XXX;fundIdentifier=XXXX;email=XXX-X.XXX@XX.com;userName=Linkexpire.Xie;timestamp=1695364328794;
Data fom encryptedToken --> fundIdentifier:XXXX -- userName:Linkexpire.Xie -- webChannel:GMD_XXX -- timeStamp:**1695364328794** -- email:XX-XX.XX@XX.com
The UID is : XXXX
userName to be searched is Linkexpire.Xie and fundName is van
Filter is cn=Linkexpire.Xie
isValidToken-->true
eclaimsAccountStatusENABLED
Inside IN-ACTIVE
The Activation URL will expire on 24/09/23
```

As seen from the above server log:
The date on which the URL in email was clicked on by the user was at: 1695364328794 ( which translates to Friday, September 22, 2023 4:32:08.794 PM GMT+10:00 )

The URL expiry date shows as: 24/09/23

i,e within 2 days the URL is getting expired.

Now the actual java code has the expiry date setting to 90 days from the date the email with the URL was generated.

Below is a sample code reproduced:

```
package com;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class TestApplication {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

      String timestamp = "1695364328794"; //Friday, September 22, 2023 4:32:08.794 PM

      validateActivationURLExpiry(timestamp);
    }

    public static void validateActivationURLExpiry(String timestamp)  {
        long timestampValue = Long.parseLong(timestamp);
        System.out.println("timestampValue:" + timestampValue);
        Date now = new Date();
        String expiryInDays = "90";
        int expiryInDay = Integer.parseInt(expiryInDays);

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestampValue);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, expiryInDay);
        long timestampValueAfter90Days = calendar.getTime().getTime();
        System.out.println("timestampValueAfter90Days:" + timestampValueAfter90Days);       

        // Code added to identify the date of URL expiry.
        Date date = new Date(timestampValueAfter90Days);
        SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
        String dateText = df2.format(date);
        System.out.println("The Activation URL will expire on " + dateText);

        if (now.getTime() > timestampValueAfter90Days) {
            System.out.println("URL has expired already ");
            //throw new UserManagementException(new Exception("URL has expired already "));
        }
    }   
}
```

The result of this program shows the URL expiry date correctly, i,e Post 90 days:

```
timestampValue:1695364328794
timestampValueAfter90Days:1703136728794
The Activation URL will expire on 21/12/23
```

The exact code is deployed on the server, not sure on the server why it's expiring within 3 days?.

Any help on this would be appreciated please..

Thanks

Regards,
R

Comment: Well, I suggest you stop using `Date`, `Calendar` and `SimpleDateFormat`. Those are obsolete classes. Instead you could use classes from the `java.time` package.

Comment: Also, you seem to be using `String`s where, IMHO, you shouldn't. For example, the variables `timestamp` and `expiryInDays` should be numeric.

Comment: @MCEmperor Nothing I know, obviously, the numbers you mention *may* come in as strings, for example from a request from another system or from configuration. Otherwise you are correct, of course.

Comment: While your code is unnecessarily complicated and as others have said, it’s bad that it uses the troublesome and outdated date-time classes, I can’t spot any bug in it. Theoretical (far-fetched?) reasons for your observed date include (1) Your `Calendar` object is not an instance of `GregorianCalendar` (though this ought not make any great difference) (2) The value of `expiryInDays` is not 90 as you think, but 2 or 3.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This is infact legacy code and not something I have written. The variables timestamp and expiryInDate are String data type variables. The value of expiryInDate is set in a properties file as a string variable. The timestamp variable is coming in as a parameter from the server. Thank you for your suggestions, I will try to check what can be changed and incorporated.

Answer (score 0):

You should be controlling the time zone / zone id this code uses, the server does not necessarily have the same one as your system.

I would do that by using `java.time` and separating the validation from any debug / info output.

Just use a method that tells you if the URL has expired or not, maybe like this:

```
public static boolean hasExpired(Instant urlCreatedAt, Instant now) {
    Instant urlExpiresAt = urlCreatedAt.plus(90, ChronoUnit.DAYS);
    return now.isAfter(urlExpiresAt);
}
```

Then provide some timestamps, pass them to the method, output their values in date-time style in a specific `ZoneId`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // provide some arbitrary url creation times
    List<Long> urlCreationTimes = List.of(
                1635364328794L,
                1655364328794L,
                1685364328794L,
                1695364328794L,
                1795364328794L
            );
    // get now
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    // define the zone you want to display the expiry date
    ZoneId serverZone = ZoneId.of("Australia/Brisbane");
    // check for each creation time if it has expired
    urlCreationTimes.forEach(creationTime -> {
        // create an Instant from the creation timestamp
        Instant createdAt = Instant.ofEpochMilli(creationTime);
        // check if the URL has expired and print out some information
        if (hasExpired(createdAt, now)) {
            System.out.println(
                String.format(
                    "The Activation URL has expired on %s",
                    createdAt.plus(90, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                             .atZone(serverZone)
                             .format(dtfDate)
                )
            );
        } else {
            System.out.println(
                String.format("The Activation URL will expire on %s",
                        createdAt.plus(90, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
                                 .atZone(serverZone)
                                 .format(dtfDate))
            );
        }
    });
}
```

This will output the *date plus offset from UTC* the URL either has expired or will expire…

```
The Activation URL has expired on 26/01/22 (+10:00)
The Activation URL has expired on 14/09/22 (+10:00)
The Activation URL has expired on 27/08/23 (+10:00)
The Activation URL will expire on 21/12/23 (+10:00)
The Activation URL will expire on 21/02/27 (+10:00)
```

You can also use the default zone id of the system by `ZoneId.systemDefault()` on the server and on your system. They are not necessarily the same and with an offset of ten hours from UTC, there's a good chance the expiry date will differ from zone id to zone id.

Comment: There’s a lot of good information and suggestions here, thanks. Ignoring the time zone issue may account for the expiration date being 1 or 2 days off, which is bad enough, not for a difference of 87 days as in the question.

Comment: That's correct, @OleV.V., this is a different option which might work on OP's server but does not explain the behaviour of the example code there. However, it might add value. I will remove this as soon as I find out it does not add value.

Comment: No problem, I actually just wanted to add value while regarding upvotes as a bonus.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. This is infact legacy code and not something I have written. The variables timestamp and expiryInDate are String data type variables. The value of expiryInDate is set in a properties file as a string variable. The timestamp variable is coming in as a parameter from the server. Thank you for your suggestions, I will try to check what can be changed and incorporated.